# How to change the border color of all tables in a Google Document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to set the border color to white for every table in my document using the script below, but even though `getColor()` returns `'#ffffff'` for each table, table borders remain the same in the actual document.

How can I get it done? And why does the code fail?

`function whiteBorders() {
    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    var tables = body.getTables();
    for(var i in tables) {
        tables[i].setBorderColor('#ffffff');
    }
}`

Comment: That seems to work fine for me on a test document. https://docs.google.com/document/d/131YEt1kvGC8A2T9athdVnY6Xv1Ib6F7alnHUoIBMTV0/edit

Comment: It does! I will report the problem to google. Something should be wrong with my  document. It didn't even work after making a copy-paste copy of it.

Comment: I've made a test document showing the bug. Could you please test it? https://docs.google.com/document/d/136lOgu-jy4a-1lsoVq1cmLOuOCNyo-7h-pOi8CO-Fek/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does it for me too and if you `Logger.log(tables[i].getAttributes());` check the logs, they say they've changed. It also fails with border width.

Comment: Are the failing tables native G Doc tables or cut/pasted in or built in some other way?

Comment: They were imported from a Europass CV template, which was in .doc or .docx.

Comment: One final comment, it looks like when I cut/paste tables from the visual editor of WordPress into G Docs the same failures occur.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you check the logs, you'll see errors on this line:

var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

I'm not an expert to give you the in-depth explanation of what caused this but I rectified your code and was able to successfully change the border colors in my Google Docs.

This is all the code:

```
function changeBorderColor() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('ENTER_DOCUMENT_ID');
   var body =doc.getBody();
    var tables = body.getTables();
    for(var i in tables) {
        tables[i].setBorderColor('#00ff00');
    }
}
```

This set my table borders to Green. Hope that helps :)

Comment: That doesn't appear to work on my test document copied from OP's. Same pattern occurs and the odd tables don't change.

Comment: Did you enter the document ID? Document must be yours. I suggest you create a google doc , insert a table, then open app script. After that get the document ID, execute my code above. It works

Comment: Yeah. I did all that. The original code works in that scenario too. If you look at the OP's issue, it's around the tables they got from a Europass CV template (whatever that is) where they won't format. They've got a link to a document you can cut paste and try vs your code.